# Select text on focus on Input Element

Tags: mobile, amp-html

When a user inputs texts, clicks elsewhere.. and reclicks on the input, how does one select all prior text on the inut??

anything thats similiar to `onfocus=this.select()`, ??

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
clarify title of question, improve text arragement, include [example] of your code, improve code formatting,
 provide more information about the problem: 
results
,
 and anything else that can help us solve your problem.
See [ask]